# Possible to test if user blocked his wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I using FB.api feed method in ordr to publish some messages in user's wall with my facebook application.

The problem is, when an user block his wall, in order to have the good fb popup i obtain the popup with the title "Error whith publishing" and the message "Cannot post to user's Wall".

Is it possible to test if an user blocked his wall?
Or is it possible to get an error from facebook and do another things?

Thanks :-).